# Keep cmus from changing terminal title

Tags: macos, cmus

Whenever I run cmus on Terminal.app, it insists on changing the terminal title to the currently playing song. And since cmus is in a separate tab almost all the time, it looks quite ugly:

[image: Ugliness]

And when I quit cmus, the title stays like this. The only way to get it back (AFAIK) is to close the tab and open a new one to replace it.

Is there any way to keep cmus from changing the terminal title altogether?

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"'`

Comment: @Ignacio: That would be fine, if I wanted *all* that in my terminal title. Is there any way to get it back to where there is nothing in my title, except for what Terminal.app itself provides?

Comment: Dunno. Try putting nothing between the `;` and the `\007`.

Comment: @Ignacio: That works, but I'm really looking for how to keep cmus from setting it at all.

Comment: That's why I didn't pose it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run `$ cmus` and enter the command

> :set set_term_title=false

Exit cmus and it will not change the title anymore.

[image: cmus with set_term_title = false]
*Image: cmus with set_term_title set to false*